How does the Leagues 5 damage reduction work?
In OSRS Leagues 5: Raging Echoes, one of the passive effects you get through the combat mastery system states simply "Damage taken is reduced by 15%." How is this damage reduction implemented? Do you take 15% fewer successful hits, or do mobs subtract 15% from their damage roll on a successful hit?

This damage reduction is calculated as a reduction of incoming max hit. For example, the max ranged hit of TzTok-Jad changes from 97 to 82.
